# How to check less than 3 minutes of data using timestamp to check using python?

Tags: python

i have dictionary data and i want to check this data activity based on timestamp

how to confirm the retrieved time if it was updated within 3 minutes is fine but if more than 3 minutes was reached it will print the results alert data

```
{'Activity': 'password changed', 'Time': '08/17/2022 08:37:15', 'UserName': 'client'}
{'Activity': 'password changed', 'Time': '08/17/2022 08:36:30', 'UserName': 'client'}
{'Activity': 'password changed', 'Time': '08/17/2022 08:35:11', 'UserName': 'client'}
{'Activity': 'password changed', 'Time': '08/17/2022 08:34:20', 'UserName': 'client'}
{'Activity': 'password changed', 'Time': '08/17/2022 08:33:20', 'UserName': 'client'}
{'Activity': 'password changed', 'Time': '07/17/2022 10:37:15', 'UserName': 'client'}
```

code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
now = datetime.now()-timedelta(minutes=3)
current_time = now.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
print(current_time)
for o in op:
    temp = o['Time']
    if current_time < temp:
        print("fine")
    else:
        print("alert")
```

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)

Comment: @MattDMo yes i updated my post with code

Answer (score 0):

from what i am understanding of your question, the problem is related to the text based nature of your time data.

here is some code to extract the amount of seconds that has passed from each timestamp

```
op1 = {'Activity': 'password changed', 'Time': '08/17/2022 08:34:20', 'UserName': 'client'}
op2 = {'Activity': 'password changed', 'Time': '08/17/2022 08:33:20', 'UserName': 'client'}
op3 = {'Activity': 'password changed', 'Time': '07/17/2022 10:37:15', 'UserName': 'client'}

op = [op1, op2, op3]

store_time = []

for o in op:
    temp = o['Time'].split(' ')
    elapsed = temp[1].split(':')  # target Time value
    hours = int(elapsed[0])
    minutes = int(elapsed[1])
    seconds = int(elapsed[2])
    total_time = hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds  # add seconds from original time
    store_time.append(total_time)
```

after that, you can store pairs of data and compare them using a simple if statement

```
if store_time[1] - store_time[0] < 180:  # 3 minutes into seconds
    print('Alert')
else:
    print('this is fine')
```

Comment: How can I get the results of an alert for the last 3 minutes of full data?
my update post timestamp is error

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

ops = [
    {'Activity': 'password changed', 'Time': '08/17/2022 08:37:15', 'UserName': 'client'},
    {'Activity': 'password changed', 'Time': '08/17/2022 08:36:30', 'UserName': 'client'},
    {'Activity': 'password changed', 'Time': '08/17/2022 08:35:11', 'UserName': 'client'},
    {'Activity': 'password changed', 'Time': '08/17/2022 08:34:20', 'UserName': 'client'},
    {'Activity': 'password changed', 'Time': '08/17/2022 08:33:20', 'UserName': 'client'},
    {'Activity': 'password changed', 'Time': '07/17/2022 10:37:15', 'UserName': 'client'}
    ]
three_mins = datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=3)
# for testing purposes
# three_mins = datetime.strptime("08/17/2022 08:34:19", "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")

for op in ops:
    t = datetime.strptime(op["Time"], "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    if three_mins <= t:
        print(t.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S") + " is fine")
    else:
        print("ALERT: " + t.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S") + " is older than " +\
            three_mins.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S") + ". DO SOMETHING!!!!")
```

The mistake you were making was that you weren't converting `op["Time"]` into a `datetime` object in the `for` loop before making the comparison in the `if` block.

If you set `three_mins` to the testing value above, this is the output:

```
08/17/2022 08:37:15 is fine
08/17/2022 08:36:30 is fine
08/17/2022 08:35:11 is fine
08/17/2022 08:34:20 is fine
ALERT: 08/17/2022 08:33:20 is older than 08/17/2022 08:34:19. DO SOMETHING!!!!
ALERT: 07/17/2022 10:37:15 is older than 08/17/2022 08:34:19. DO SOMETHING!!!!
```